# How do I rename "_arg" in a destructured function argument?

Tags: coffeescript, destructuring

I have a reduce function like this:

```
ops = rqOps.reduce (p, { commit: id: cid, type: type }, idx, arr) ->
    # Do stuff here
    p
, {}
```

which works fine, but now the name of the second argument compiles to `_arg`. How can I give it a different name? I've tried several different approaches like `arg = { commit: id: cid, type: type }` and `{ commit: id: cid, type: type } : arg` and `{ commit: id: cid, type: type } = arg` but nothing compiles to the intended result. What's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you care what the second argument is called? Your object destructuring means that you wouldn't work with that argument at all, you'd just work with `cid` and `type` instead. The `_arg` name and even its existence is subject to change and none of your business.

For example, if you have this:

```
rqOps = [
    { commit: { id: 1, type: 2 } }
    { commit: { id: 2, type: 4 } }
]
ops = rqOps.reduce (p, { commit: id: cid, type: type }, idx, arr) ->
    console.log(cid, type)
    p
, { }
```

then you'll get `1, 2` and `2, 3` in the console. If you want the whole second argument then give it a name and unpack it inside the iterator function:

```
ops = rqOps.reduce (p, arg, idx, arr) ->
    { commit: id: cid, type: type } = arg
    #...
```

Comment: Your last block does replace `_arg` with `arg`.  There's no other difference in the compiled code.

Comment: @hpaulj: Sorry, misread your comment the first time, my eyes saw "doesn't" instead of "does".

Comment: I want to reference the second argument because I only want to destructure a few of its properties. What if the object has 100 properties and I only want to destructure 2 of them while still having access to the others?

Comment: Then use the second approach: give it a name in the argument list and pull out the parts you want inside the function body.